# appmaker : I get error com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Path segment does not exist

Tags: runtime-error, google-app-maker

When trying to update a datasource, by unload , set parameter , load,
appmaker bings following error on the frontend :
com.google.web.bindery.event.shared.UmbrellaException: Exception caught: Path segment does not exist

The data is showing properly, but the spinner never stops...

What's the problem ?

Comment: Do you have any code to share? I'm working on a similar issue.

Comment: Hi, is there any update on this? Has anyone been able to figure out the root cause of this exception in app maker. I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: @Chadd Can I ask you incase you have figured out the root cause as you were working on a similar issue. Thanks.

Comment: @ab.it.gcp I did work through it. I do not remember what I changed to fix it. The error doesn't really help and does not lead one to the real issue.

Comment: Me too. I just started all over again with the original template and the error did not come. Previously I was using a template which my colleague had modified on top of the original template.